# Selecting every second cell in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to select the highlighted cells

[image: shown here].

The range extends from A2 to EL2 so 72 in total.

I think I need to create a vector that is [2,4,6...] then use that result to select the cells.

Currently my code is not working and is...

```
range(cells(2, 2*(1 To 72))).select
```

I'm stuck and need some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should assist, might not be the easiest way..

```
Sub sel()

Dim l As Long
Dim r As Range

For l = 2 To 22 Step 2
    If r Is Nothing Then
        Set r = Cells(2, l)
    Else
        Set r = Union(r, Cells(2, l))
    End If
Next l

r.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
Dim rng_exp As Range, x As Integer
Set rng_exp = Cells(2, 2)

For x = 2 To 72
    Set rng_exp = Application.Union(rng_exp, Cells(2, 2 * (x)))
Next

rng_exp.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, use a loop:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("B2")
    For i = 4 To 142 Step 2
        Set r = Union(r, Cells(2, i))
    Next i
    r.Select
End Sub
```